# Can I transfer to a university in Europe from Turkey?

Tags: university, europe, international-students, transfer-student, abroad

Currently, I am studying at METU (ODTÜ) Computer Engineering/Science, Bachelor's Degree. I am not happy with the situation here. My department is ABET-accredited, but I am a non-EU citizen. Is it possible for me to transfer to a European University from here? If it is, what about tuition fees, etc.? Are there any foundations where I can get financial aid?

Comment: I don't know off about the process. But if you are at the beginning of your course, then at least you can restart the same course in Europe. I wish you get what you desire.

Comment: Oftentimes, you could start the same/similar program and get some of the courses you already passed to transfer to your new university. This way, you would not loose all your progress.

Comment: One of our current PhD students went exactly this way. So it is definitely possible. I do not know much about the regulations involved, unfortunately.

Comment: I can't answer, but suspect that transfer is possible, but funding is much much harder. Look also into funding from some organization in your home country. You can ask at any place you apply to, of course.

Comment: @Snijderfrey Do you know how to get information about this situation? Where should  I send an email, to universities or someplace else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: At my university, I would start asking at our international office. Their main job is to make sure that international students get support especially with the regulatory issues they have to sort out. They are also usually willing to help, unlike official authorities which tend to make things more complicated.